# Find the probability that a person has a headache given that the person has a fever.

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

For the problem below are we going to use the equiprobable space.

Which is in particular, if $S$ contains n points then the probability of each point is $1/n$. For an event $A$, $P(A) =$ (number of elements in $A$)(number of elements in $S) = |A||S|$.

Question :

> Suppose that the probability of a person having a headache is $0.01$,
>   that the probability of a person having a fever given that the person
>   has a headache is $0.4$, and that the probability of a person having a
>   fever is $0.02$. Find the probability that a person has a headache given
>   that the person has a fever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Bayes' Theorem, 
$$ P(A | B) = \frac{P(B|A) P(A)}{P(B)}
$$
denote "has a headache" by A and "has a fever" by B

then by a straight forward application of Bayes' we have

$$ P(A | B) = \frac{P(B|A) P(A)}{P(B)} = \frac {0.4 * 0.01}{0.02} = 0.2
$$